# CSS Styling is not working in Angular 6 after using angular material

Tags: bootstrap-4, angular-material, angular6

I have used bootstrap with Angular 6 to design a web page. Then I added material sidenav including all the imports required. Now the CSS is not getting applied. Can someone let me know is the styling getting overriden by material styles. How do I use the original styles provided by angular/bootstrap for textboxes and buttons.

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { NavigationComponent } from './navigation/navigation.component';
import { CostShareComponent } from './cost-share/cost-share.component';
import { PenaltyComponent } from './penalty/penalty.component';
import {RouterModule, Routes} from "@angular/router";
import {CustomMaterialModule} from "./core/material.module";
import {ContractService} from './service/contract.service';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { NgbdModalContent } from './app-modal.component';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: CostShareComponent, data: { title: 'Cost Share' } },
  { path: 'cost-share', component: CostShareComponent, data: { title: 'Cost Share' } },
  { path: 'penalty', component: PenaltyComponent, data: { title: 'Penalty' } }
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavigationComponent,
    CostShareComponent,
    PenaltyComponent,
    NgbdModalContent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    HttpModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(
      appRoutes,
      { useHash: true }
      ),
    CustomMaterialModule
  ],
  providers: [ContractService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [NgbdModalContent],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

xyz.component.html

```
<div class="container" style="background-color: lightblue;">
    <br/><h1 style="text-align: center;">
      Cost Share Conditions
    </h1><br/>
    <br/>
  <form *ngIf="addForm" [formGroup]="addForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <div *ngIf="successMessage" class="alert alert-success">
      <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
      <strong>Success!</strong> {{successMessage}}
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="errorMessage" class="alert alert-danger">
    <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
      <strong>Error!</strong> {{errorMessage | json}}
    </div>
    <table>
  <thead></thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="contractId" ng-model="contractId" style="display: none;"/>
    </td>
     <td>
     <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
        <label for="contractName">Contract Name:</label>
        <input formControlName="contractName" placeholder="Contract Name" class="form-control" name="contractName" id="contractName">
     <!--  <div *ngIf="submitted && f.contractName.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                              <div *ngIf="f.contractName.errors.required">Contract Name is required</div>
                          </div> -->
                      </div>
     </td>
     <td>
   <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
       <h4 style="margin-left:100px;">Penalty Conditions</h4>
      </div>
  </td>  
  </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
  <div formArrayName="contractServiceList">
  <div *ngFor="let items of contractList.controls; let i=index" 
              [formGroupName]="i">
  <table>
  <thead></thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr> 
  <td>
      <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
        <label for="serviceId">Category Of Services:</label>
        <select id ="serviceId" [(ngModel)]="serviceId" formControlName="serviceId" name="serviceId" class="form-control">
      <option value="1">Emergency Room</option>
      <option value="2">OP Radiology</option>
  </select>
        </div>
      </td>
  <td>
   <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
        <label for="penaltyApplies">Penalty Applies:</label>
         <select id ="penaltyApplies" formControlName="penaltyApplies" name="penaltyApplies" class="form-control">
      <option>Y</option>
      <option>N</option>
  </select>
  </div>
  </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>
      <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
        <label for="copay">Copay Amount:</label>
        <input formControlName="copay" placeholder="Copay Amount" class="form-control" name="copay" id="copay">
      <!-- <div *ngIf="submitted && addForm.controls.contractServiceList.controls[i].controls.copay.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                              <div *ngIf="addForm.controls.contractServiceList.controls[i].controls.copay.errors.required">Copay is required</div>
                          </div> -->
      </div>
      </td>
      <td>
      <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
        <label for="penaltyRule">Penalty Rule:</label>
         <select id ="penaltyRule" formControlName="penaltyRule" name="penaltyRule" class="form-control">
      <option>Non Emergency ER Use</option>
  </select>
        </div>
      </td>
      </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>
      <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
        <label for="deductibleApplies">Deductible Applies:</label>
          <select id ="deductibleApplies" formControlName="deductibleApplies" name="deductibleApplies" class="form-control">
      <option>Y</option>
      <option>N</option>
  </select>
  </div>
      </td>
      <td>
      <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
        <label for="penaltyType">Penalty Type:</label>
        <select id ="penaltyType" name="penaltyType" formControlName="penaltyType" class="form-control">
      <option>Coinsurance</option>
      <option>Dollar Amount</option>
  </select>
  </div>
      </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <td>
      <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
        <label for="coinsurance">CoInsurance:</label>
        <input formControlName="coinsurance" placeholder="Coinsurance" name="coinsurance" class="form-control" id="coinsurance">
      </div>
      </td>
      <td>
      <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
        <label for="penaltyValue">Penalty Value:</label>
        <input formControlName="penaltyValue" placeholder="Penalty Value" name="penaltyValue" class="form-control" id="penaltyValue">
      </div>
      </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>
      <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
        <label for="deductibleAppliesPenalty">Deductible Applies:</label>
        <select id ="deductibleAppliesPenalty" name="deductibleAppliesPenalty" formControlName="deductibleAppliesPenalty" class="form-control">
      <option>Y</option>
      <option>N</option>
  </select>
      </div>
      </td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row text-center">
      <div class="col-12">
      <button class="btn btn-success" [disabled]="!addForm.valid">Save</button>
      <button style="margin-left: 20px" class="btn btn-success" (click)="onReset()">Reset</button>
      </div>
      </div>
    </form>
    <br/><br/>
    <br/>
  </div>
```

Comment: Please clarify your question. The code you've shared doesn't use any Angular Material components. Which CSS is "not getting applied"? Please see Angular and Bootstrap documentation for the answers to "How do I use the original styles provided by angular/bootstrap for textboxes and buttons?"

Comment: Material is used for navigation <mat-sidenav-container class="all-wrap" fullscreen>
  <mat-sidenav mode="side" opened role="navigation">
      <h3>Benefit Coding</h3>
    <mat-nav-list>
      <a mat-list-item routerLinkActive="active" routerLink='/cost-share'>Cost Share</a>
      <a mat-list-item routerLink='/penalty'>Penalty</a>
    </mat-nav-list>
  </mat-sidenav>
  <mat-sidenav-content>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>

Comment: Also I see angular.json styling code is applied but not sure why it's not applied -  "styles": [
              {
                "input": "node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css"
              },
              "src/styles.css"
            ],

Comment: Please fix your original question, and if possible create your example on StackBlitz.